# Error tuple: Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Integral (a, a)

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have seen an example where you define the tuple type in this way:

```
countRepetitions :: (Integral a, Integral (a,a)) => [a] -> a -> (a,a)
```

But when I execute the code appears the message:
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: `Integral (a, a)`
How can I declare a tuple type?

Comment: What do you mean with "declare a tuple type"? Actually it rather weird to state this because a tuple is not really integral: it is hard to convert it to a nice "Integer"...

Comment: It's [not hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer#Construction), but not particularly useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to constraint with `Integral (a, a)`. The constraint `Integral a` forces all values for type `a` to be `Integral`. Try rewriting it like this:

```hs
countRepetitions :: Integral a => [a] -> a -> (a,a)
```

Comment: What if the second element of the tuple is of any type?

Comment: If you want a parameter to be of any type, use an unconstrained generic parameter. For example, this makes the second argument of the function unconstrained: `countRepetitions :: Integral a => [a] -> b -> (a,a)`. However, returning a type of `(a,b)`, where you are returning something completely unknown as the second parameter, may not be what you're after.